# Comparing multiple strings in Java

Tags: java, string, if-statement, compare

I have 5 distinct strings called, say, string1 through string5.

I want to write a simple if statement that runs if any two of the five strings contain the same string. How would I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know lot of answers on the way, mean while can you show your efforts ?

Comment: Put them in a `Set` and see how big it gets.

Comment: @tobias_k Won't work: OP wants to check `contain the same string`.

Comment: You can't write "a simple if statement" for that. You'll need a for-loop as well, possibly more than one.

Comment: You mean, like, whether any of the strings contain the same substring, even if it's just a single character? Could you please elaborate and also provide a few examples?

Comment: @tobias_k I think we're actually looking at an NP-class problem, especially if OP wants the *maximal* string with his property.

Comment: You could put all the substrings (or in fact all the characters) in a set... still not sure I understand the question, though.

Comment: If the "same string" which the strings must contain is specified in advance, then this reduces to a trivial problem.

Comment: @tobias_k And then you would have an obvious proof that the problem is of the NP variety. How many substrings are there for an N-character long string?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Without example input and output, we can't know for sure what the asker meant - given language barriers and that people don't always express themselves perfectly, it could be either, or maybe even something completely different - another reason to close the question as unclear.

Comment: A _simple if statement_ would be `if(checkWhateverConditionIsNeeded(String...))` ;)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You just have to find out whether they share a substring, not to find the longest common substring or such. Depending on what is meant with "contain the same string", you can put all the characters in sets and see whether the word you are currently looking at has any of those. Should be O(n), unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @tobias_k I can hardly imagine OP would be interested in something on that level of triviality. If he wanted common characters, then he would say "common characters".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparison is a binary operation, therefore you can always compare only two objects at a time. I would suggest using a cycle and comparing each string to the remaining ones.

```
public boolean multipleStringEquals(String[] strings) {

    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < strings.length; j++) {
            if (strings[i].equals(strings[j])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Yeah you're right, fixed. Thanks

Comment: @ambigram_maker Why? It is checking, whether *any* two strings are equal, not all of them.

Comment: Right... It does really ask for one duplicate. (Sorry).